# How to integrate $\int \frac{2x^2+x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate $\displaystyle \int \frac{2x^2+x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}dx$? I Tried using partial fractions but i got lost, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Partial fractions are the way to go. The fraction is already reduced, and the denominator is fully factored over the reals, so your setup is

$$\frac{2x^2+x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}=\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+1}=\frac{A(x^2+1)+(Bx+C)(x+1)}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}\;,$$

and you must find $A,B$, and $C$ so that $$2x^2+x=A(x^2+1)+(Bx+C)(x+1)=(A+B)x^2+(B+C)x+(A+C)\;.$$

Equating coefficients of powers of $x$ yields the system

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&A+B=2\\
&B+C=1\\
&A+C=0\;,
\end{align*}\right.$$

which is easily solved: $A=\frac12,B=\frac32$, and $C=-\frac12$. Thus,

$$\frac{2x^2+x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}=\frac1{2(x+1)}+\frac{3x-1}{2(x^2+1)}\;,$$ and

$$\int\frac{2x^2+x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}dx=\frac12\int\frac1{x+1}dx+\frac12\int\frac{3x-1}{x^2+1}dx\;.$$

You shouldn’t have any trouble with $\int\frac1{x+1}dx$. The other term is most easily handled by splitting it:

$$\int\frac{3x-1}{x^2+1}dx=3\int\frac{x}{x^2+1}dx-\int\frac1{x^2+1}dx\;,$$

where the first integral succumbs to a $u$-substitution, and the second is one that you should know (or at least be able to work by a trig substitution).

Comment: @Marvis: You’re right, of course. I’m fixing it now.

Comment: There is a trick known as the "cover-up rule" which gets you the constants which go with linear factors - in the expression for $2x^2+x$ set $x=-1$ which immediately gives you an expression for $A$. In this case you could deal with the quadratic factor and get $B$ and $C$ by setting $x=\pm i$. It is called the cover-up rule because it is computable directly from the original expression for partial fractions by computing the LHS after covering up a factor in the denominator and evaluating what remains.

Comment: @MarkBennet: I usually choose this "rule" for finding constants. It often works good.

Comment: @Mark: Interesting: I’d never heard it given a name. It’s a nice shortcut, but I definitely think of it as an extra.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to write $(2x^2 + x)$ as $A(x^2+1) + (Bx+C)(x+1)$
$$(2x^2 + x) = A(x^2+1) + (Bx+C)(x+1) = (A+B)x^2 + (B+C)x + (A+C)$$
This gives us $A+B = 2$, $B+C = 1$ and $A+C = 0$ i.e. $A+B = 2$ and $B-A = 1$.

$$A = \dfrac12, B = \dfrac32, C = -\dfrac12$$

Hence, $$\dfrac{2x^2+x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)} = \dfrac1{2(x+1)} + \dfrac{3x-1}{2(x^2+1)} = \dfrac1{2(x+1)} + \dfrac34 \dfrac{2x}{x^2+1} - \dfrac12 \dfrac1{x^2+1}$$

Now you should be able to integrate it.

Answer (score 0):

From $\frac{2x^2+ x}{(x+ 1)(x^2+ 1)}= \frac{A}{x+ 1}+ \frac{Bx+ C}{x^2+ 1}$ you can add the fractions on the right, then compare coefficients of "like terms".  But we can also use the fact that this is to be true for **all** x.  Setting x to any three values gives three equations to solve for A, B, and C.

First multiplying both sides by $x+1$ and $x^2+ 1$ simplifies to $2x^2+ x= A(x^2+ 1)+ (Bx+ C)(x+ 1).

Setting x= -1 immediately gives $2(1)+ (-1)= 1= A(2)$ so $A= \frac{1}{2}$.

Setting x= 0 gives $0= A+ C= \frac{1}{2}+ C$ so $C= -\frac{1}{2}$.

Setting x= 1 gives $2+ 1= 3= 2A+ 2(B+ C)= 1+ 2B- 1$ so $B= \frac{3}{2}$.